# In php how can I monitor Apache workers?

Tags: php, apache

Is there a way in php that I can get the current number of idle, waiting, working etc. workers in Apache?

Similar to the information available in the WHM Apache Status page.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [mod_status](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_status.html) to monitor your apache server.Also this is a good [tutorial](http://www.tecmint.com/monitor-apache-web-server-load-and-page-statistics/) to set it up.

Comment: Thanks, but it does not really indicate how to get access to it in php. I guess scraping the status page is one way, but surely there must be a better way?

Comment: Well , this is the only good way I know, and yes parse the status page and cache it in case of repeated access is the way I used it myself.